# цвет фона выбранной даты в CalendarView

Tags: calendar-view

Есть CalendarView, мне нужно сменить цвет выбранной даты со стандартного, красного , на голубой, как это сделать?
[image: красный цвет]

[image: синий цвет]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добился этого при помощи com.prolificinteractive.materialcalendarview.MaterialCalendarView
Опции app:mcv_selectionColor="@color/blue"